# How to use *nix find command to search for specific files with regular expression

Tags: centos, find

In my centOS there is a lot of log files in my folder /log

```
/log/log.20120308
/log/log.20120308.1
/log/log.20120308.2
/log/log.20120308.3
/log/log.20120308.error
/log/log.20120308.error.1
```

Apparently if I use command like below

```
find /log -type f -iregex '.*/'log.20120308'.[0-9]*' -print
```

I will only get

```
/log/log.20120308.1
/log/log.20120308.2
/log/log.20120308.3
```

I hoping to have the right regular expression to get the list below but fail

```
/log/log.20120308
/log/log.20120308.1
/log/log.20120308.2
/log/log.20120308.3
```

I couldn't figure out the regular expression to select extension .1, .2, .3 or blank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find /log -type f -iregex '.*/'log.20120308'\(\.[0-9]*\)?' -print
```

the `?` indicates one or none, and you should escape the dot (before the [0-9] since dot matches *everything*), so if you don't escape the dot, you would also get `/log/log.20120308_1` in the result if that file is existed.

Comment: I like this version also.  And note that you can leave out that last `*` if you only have single-digit numbers after the `.` that you want to find.

Answer (score 2):

One version:

```
find /log -type f -iregex '.*/'log.20120308'[.0-9]*' -print
```

Of course, this would also select a file that was named `/log/log.20120308..`, but I don't imagine that would be a likely problem.

Another way would be to use `-o` as an "or" operator, with escaped parentheses around the operands:

```
find /log -type f \( -iregex '.*/'log.20120308'.[0-9]*' -o -iregex '.*/'log.20120308 \) -print
```

Oh, one more update for the use of `-iregex`:  you can simply your quoting somewhat, since `'.*/log.20120308.[0-9]*'` would select the same as `'.*/'log.20120308'.[0-9]*'`  Putting this together with the suggestion by @md-gao, you could get this version:

```
find /log -type f -iregex '.*/log.20120308\(\.[0-9]\)?' -print
```